# Is it possible to schedule a sudo upgrade?

Tags: runtime-upgrade

We've tried to use the scheduler pallet using both `enact_authorized_upgrade` and `setCode`, but because the scheduler pallet executes [on_initialize](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/scheduler/src/lib.rs#L305-L314) and it appears that the upgrades cannot happen without the validation data which doesn't exist yet `on_initialize` (See: [Runtime upgrade error: parachainSystem.ValidationDataNotAvailable](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2309/runtime-upgrade-error-parachainsystem-validationdatanotavailable))

Is there some other way that I have missed to be able to predetermine the block of a sudo upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some other way that I have missed to be able to predetermine the block of a sudo upgrade?

If you want to use `scheduler`, you have to use `authorize_upgrade` and then anyone can send the `enact_authorized_upgrade` transaction. However, exactly determining the point on when the runtime upgrade will happen is not that easy. When the Parachain has signaled to the relay chain the intend to upgrade, there is some minimum time until the upgrade is applied. However, as the majority of relay chain validators need to approve the upgrade (to check that it compiles etc), the actual time between signaling and enacting can be longer.

TDLR, you can not predetermine for sure the exact block when it will happen.

Answer (score 1):

Parachains need to schedule runtime upgrades with the relay chain. This process is already handled for you with a set of custom extrinsics coming from the `parachain-system` pallet.

There are details here: https://decentration.medium.com/how-to-make-a-parachain-runtime-upgrade-2b0e063fe1f7

Comment: Ah that "schedule" for runtime upgrade is scheduling with the relay chain. I kept trying to understand how it worked with the scheduler pallet.