# How to make a main net parachain upgrade through democracy?

Tags: parachain, runtime-upgrade, democracy

I have made successful runtime upgrades through the sudo pallet prior to this, but after trying to do it through referendum using the democracy pallet there was an [error](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fkabocha.jelliedowl.net#/explorer/query/835200). [image]

What are the step to make a runtime upgrade through democracy?

I have a sense that anytime i upload the compact.compressed Wasm file it doesn't work but if i copy and past the Wasm code from a build-spec it does work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Runtime upgrade error: parachainSystem.ValidationDataNotAvailable](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2309/runtime-upgrade-error-parachainsystem-validationdatanotavailable)

Comment: ive done the enact and authorize route. I have done quite a few mainnet upgrades via sudo, https://decentration.medium.com/how-to-make-a-parachain-runtime-upgrade-2b0e063fe1f7

On the first ever refendum upgrade i used sudo to create the `AuthorizeUpgrad`e, then i made a referendum to run the `enactAuthorizeUpgrade`, which took about 2 weeks, and produced an error. I think perhaps its a because i uploaded a compact comptessed wasm file, and i only have ever copy pasted wasm from a build spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you only need to do the `authorize_upgrade` through referendum which require a root origin.

After that, anyone can call `enact_authorized_upgrade`.

As I mentioned in my comment. Check [Runtime upgrade error: parachainSystem.ValidationDataNotAvailable](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2309/runtime-upgrade-error-parachainsystem-validationdatanotavailable).

You should not run the `enact_authorized_upgrade` in `on_initialize`. And the referendum is a schedule call. That's why you got this error.

---

https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/f3847ead3c8570a2a6f05924c5fdc8a34686365c/pallets/parachain-system/src/lib.rs#L456

As you can see, you don't need a root origin to run `enact_authorized_upgrade`.

Comment: i see i seee. right that really helps thanks!!