# What's the best way to perfrom a parachain runtime upgrade through democracy?

Tags: parachain, runtime-upgrade

Today, I attempted to submit a preimage, start an external proposal and initiate referenda.

Check the preimage here: https://crab.subscan.io/referenda/4?tab=proposal_preimage.

The outcome of my efforts can be found at https://crab.subscan.io/block/170147?tab=event&event=170147-0. However, I encountered an error which stated that the inherent responsible for providing validation data did not run during this block (ValidationDataNotAvailable).

```rs
/// The inherent which supplies the validation data did not run this block
ValidationDataNotAvailable,
```

I am curious if the priority of scheduled extrinsics is higher than that of inherent extrinsics. It appears that the scheduled referenda were applied before `set_validation_data`.

What would be the best approach in such a scenario? If the preimage is a `ParachainSystem::authorize_upgrade` instead of a batch call, sending `ParachainSystem::enact_authorized_upgrade` separately will result in high transaction fees.

Comment: You already answered this yourself? https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6285/how-to-make-a-main-net-parachain-upgrade-through-democracy/6293#6293

Comment: But enact this myself would cause a lot of tx fee (the wasm is large). It looks like we don’t have any other ways to avoid that…

Comment: `enact_authorized_upgrade` currently has a static weight? So, that doesn't change with the size of the wasm file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. Thanks to @bkchr.

The `enact_authorized_upgrade` currently has a static weight. It won't cost too much.

---

I believe we can request funding for runtime upgrades from the treasury, regardless of the cost. The treasury will support us, whether it is a significant or minor expense.